# What is a good, common alternative for the "He is the engine of the group" expression?

Tags: expressions, translation

In French, to say that someone is the key element of the dynamic of a group, we can use the expression "she/he is the engine of the group" (Elle/Il est le moteur du groupe). This clearly shows that this person is what moves the group forward.

**What would be a similar expression in English**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

> He is the **driving force** behind/of the group.

"driving force" is similar to what an "engine" does, and I would prefer "behind" since he/she is pushing it along.

Answer (score 1):

One expression that might work is:

> He is the **leader of the pack**.

TFD defines “lead the pack* as:

> To be at the forefront of a particular group, either literally or figuratively.

It’s a relatively common expression, much thanks to a hit song from the 1960s by the Shangri-Las.

It’s often used in sports journalism, when talking about leaders of teams. For example, one photo from the Boston Herald was captioned:

> [LEADER OF THE PACK](https://www.bostonherald.com/2018/05/27/nfl-notes-julian-edelman-makes-presence-felt-with-patriots/): Julian Edelman holds court with the receivers group during the Pats’ OTA workout on Tuesday in Foxboro.

while a news story about a local high school wrestling team said:

> Senior Joe Hackett is the [leader of the pack](http://www.tribtoday.com/sports/high-school-sports/2018/12/2018-19-area-wrestling-preview-division-iii/). The returning district qualifier is a longtime wrestler who was unanimously named captain, and for good reason.